How to bevel a curve using the geometry of another object
I have a Curve. I want to bevel the curve using the geometry of another object. In this example, the other curve is a Rectangle, and it is called ‘Rectangle’.
So, I select the first Curve then:
Curve properties > Geometry > Bevel > Object > Select ‘Rectangle’.
The result - after converting to Mesh - (see below) is almost what I want, but how do I get rid of the rounded edges??
I have also included an image of the same mesh in wireframe view. It looks perfect there!



It doesn't seem to be rounded, it's just the shading that is smoothed by default when you used a curve, to fix that, right click and choose Shade Flat.

Doh. Thank you!
